# Change error message text: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"

Tags: java, android

I want to change error Toast content from "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" to something like "Unable to connect the internet. Please check your connection.". Can i even do this and if i can - how?

Comment: Share the code which is displaying the toast message. You can use the HTTP response code or the error handler to display your own custom message.

Comment: That is the problem. I dont know where i can find location of this code.

Comment: Find with the string id in your project. That should be quick or do a code flow. This is something which you need to figure out. Or find with Toast.

Comment: @Soumya Please, can you help me. How i can find strings using its content in Android Studio?

Comment: Intercept the exception and execute your code on error.

Comment: Search for the string in strings.xml and then using the string id search for it in the entire codebase. This is a crude way of doing it and you might find multiple places. So anyone who has knowledge of the code needs to point you out specifically.

Comment: @Soumya but in strings.xml i can find only my own introdiced strings. There are no error message strings.

Comment: Hmm, then it is displaying the error message returned by the HTTP client. In that case, you have to find out the exact flow in which the error is being raised.

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap the code in a try and catch exception the customize your error message int the catch clause e.g

```
try {

} catch (Exception ex) {
  /**
   *customize your error message here
  **/
}
```